# Building an app that creates 360 degree panoramic photo

Tags: mobile

Got a request from a client to build a mobile app that has the ability to create a 360 degree panoramic photo (while spherical isnt a necessity, must at least be cylindrical).

I am trying to find some mobile frameworks that offer the functionality, but coming up mostly blank.
I have found a number of viewers, which is helpful, but no SDK that can actually capture the image. There are apps on the app store that do this, so not sure if they are using a common library or if it was developed in-house.
Google Sphere is kinda what Im looking for, but it seems like Google Sphere is limited to be used only within their apps.

Is anybody familiar with a framework that I can use for this? Else, can you offer any alternative advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's allowed to make it a web service that can be called from the app? The app can send a picture or range of pictures to the web service, and the web service can put the pictures together into a format that can be viewed with a 360 viewer. That way you're not limited to libraries that run on mobile.

Comment: That could also be a possible solution. But now the question is, are you familiar of any of these web services by any chance? :)

Comment: Nope. Just trying to broaden your possiblities. :)

Comment: ah thanks! Good suggestion though, will try do some digging around that space! :)